# Fallo al usar la variable $request de Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, requests

Hola a todos gracias por leer mi pregunta, me encuentro en la siguiente situación tengo una función en mi controlador la cual se va encargar de combinar dos arrays que me llegan por medio de un formulario he observado que el objeto $request es el que provoca la falla ya que he pasado una variable estatica en lugar del $request y esto funciona a la perfección les comparto mi función y voy comentando en el error y lo que quiero lograr.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) 
    {
        try {
            // $request =  [1,"Darwin","20","soltero"]; Esto es lo que recibe desde la vista
           
            $columns = Schema::getColumnListing($id);  // ["id","nombre","edad","estado_civil"]
            
            $consulta = array_combine ($columns,$request); //Aquí es donde he observado que falla debuggeando me di cuenta de esto.
            return $consulta; 

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
            ], 200);

        } catch (\Exception | \Error $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'No se pudo completar la accion',
            ], 500);
        }
    }
```

Me he dado cuenta de algo en mis pruebas si retorno $request antes de todo de esta manera:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id) 
        {
            try {
                return $request; // AQUÍ ESTOY RETONANDO 
               
                $columns = Schema::getColumnListing($id);
                $rows = $request;
                $consulta = array_combine ($columns,$rows) ;
                return $consulta;
     
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => true,
                ], 200);
    
            } catch (\Exception | \Error $e) {
                return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'No se pudo completar la accion',
                ], 500);
            }
        }
```

Esto me retorna lo siguiente:

```
[1,"Darwin","20","soltero"]
```

Y si retorno el $request en mi return de la función de esta manera:

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
try {

```
        return response()->json([
            'request' => $request,
            'success' => true,
        ], 200);

    } catch (\Exception | \Error $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'No se pudo completar la accion',
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

Como resultado me arroja esto:

```
  {"request":{"attributes":{},"request":{},"query":{},"server":{},"files":{},"cookies":{},"headers":{}},"success":true}
```

Gracias por sus respuestas y opiniones les agradeceria mucho cualquier tipo de información sobre el tema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es un problema del $request , sino de PHP y lo que está intentando combinar, la variable $request es un objeto de tipo Request, mas no un array tipo Array() , al parecer la función array_combine lo está aceptando por que lo interpreta como una colección y bueno, ahí sale el resultado extraño, que en sí lo que está mostrando son los atributos del objeto $request de tipo Request.
Normalmente yo eperaría algo como $request->miArray; , si realiza un var_dump($request); le debe mostrar que es de tipo Object y no Array. Esa sería mi teoría, jeje

Answer (score 1):

El problema es el que menciona @DavidTapias el $request es un objeto  de tipo Request por lo tanto es de tipo Object la solucion a esto es pasar todo lo que tenga $request a una nueva variable solucione de la siguiente forma:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id) 
        {
            try {    
                $columns = Schema::getColumnListing($id);
                $rows = $request->all(); //AQUÍ ES DONDE HA CAMBIADO
                $consulta = array_combine ($columns,$rows) ;
                return $consulta;
     
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => true,
                ], 200);
    
            } catch (\Exception | \Error $e) {
                return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'No se pudo completar la accion',
                ], 500);
            }
        }
```